# Why does Perl not want to require certain files when running under -T?

Tags: perl, require, taint

I recently noticed that on my system it is not possible to `require 'lib/file.pl'` when running under `-T`, but `require './lib/file.pl'` works.

```
$ perl -wT -e 'require "lib/file.pl";'
Can't locate lib/file.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl)

$ perl -wT -e 'require "lib/file.pl"'
```

Doing it without `-T` works in both ways:
    $ perl -w -e 'require "lib/file.pl"'
    $ perl -w -e 'require "./lib/file.pl"'

In taint mode, `.` is not part of `@INC`.

```
perl -w -e 'print "@INC"'
[..snip..] /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .
perl -wT -e 'print "@INC"'
[..snip..] /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
```

I could not find that behavior in the doc. Can someone please tell me where this is documented or why `-T` doesn't like `.` as a lib directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Erm... this is actually [well documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode-and-@INC), I suppose:

> When the taint mode (-T ) is in effect, the "." directory is removed
>   from @INC , and the environment variables PERL5LIB and PERLLIB are
>   ignored by Perl. You can still adjust @INC from outside the program by
>   using the -I command line option as explained in perlrun.

... but that's only a half on an answer, I suppose. The reasons behind such decision are given [here](http://gunther.web66.com/FAQS/taintmode.html#require):

> ... the issue with @INC is really more of a problem with SUID scripts
>   than CGI scripts. When you have an SUID script that can execute with
>   the permissions of another user (such as root), Perl goes into
>   taintmode automatically.
>
> For this SUID script case, it would be a huge security breach to have
>   the capability of loading libraries from the user's current directory.
>   If a script ends up having a bug where the library is not found in the
>   normal directory path, then a user could exploit this by writing their
>   own, malicious version of the library, putting it in the current
>   directory, and running the SUID script from their current directory.
>
> However, this is not really the same problem with CGI scripts. User's
>   are not executing your script from arbitrary directories. Your web
>   server controls which directory the script is called from. So keeping
>   "." in @INC is not really a problem compared to SUID scripts which
>   operate under taint mode automatically.

Comment: I just didn't see that. Right now I'm reading in *Programming Perl* but still did not find that part. **Thank you!**